# Problem with multi conversion into array elements

Tags: vbscript, qtp

We are using a code as follows

split(Window(window_name).Dialog(dialog_name).WinList(control_name).GetSelection
which returns the values as 
F2
F3
F5

However when i try to split the same, to store the values in the array selected_values as follows,
selected_values = split(Window(window_name).Dialog(dialog_name).WinList(control_name).GetSelection," ",-1,1)

selected_values is not stored as single elements, instead selected_values(0) shows result as 
F2
F3
F5
how can i store the multiline elements in single array? I couldnt split the string based on space and couldn't introduce line break for the same..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just found out:

using the follwoing code solves the issue:

selected_values = split(Window(window_name).Dialog(dialog_name).WinList(control_name).GetSelection,vbLf,-1,1)

now selected_values array contains single elements